Why is React Native FlatList not updating after I add a new item?
I'm working on a React-Native app where I display a list of items using FlatList. I want to add new items to the list dynamically, but for some reason, the list does not update immediately when I add an item to the array.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([{ id: '1', name: 'Item 1' }]);

  const addItem = () => {
    const newItem = { id: (data.length + 1).toString(), name: `Item ${data.length + 1}` };
    setData([...data, newItem]);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Add Item" onPress={addItem} />
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

When I press the "Add Item" button, I expect the new item to appear immediately in the FlatList, but nothing happens. I’ve tried using console.log after updating it, and the new item does get added to the array, but the FlatList does not seem to re-render.

I copy/pasted your code into a running Snack and it runs and updates without issue. I can't reproduce the problem you describe using the code you provided.

Weird!! Let me check it out again. Does this depend on the local environment setup to Snack setup?

Update the addItem to below given function.
const addItem = () => {
const newItem = { id: (data.length + 1).toString(), name: `Item ${data.length + 1}` };
setData([...data, ...newItem]);
};


Force Re-render: Another way is to use the extraData prop, which forces FlatList to re-render when data changes.
<FlatList
    data={data}
    extraData={data} // Force FlatList to re-render on data change
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
/>


If you need to force a rerender, by definition you're doing it wrong.
